# How to pass a property to an Handlebars helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to register a Handlebars.js helper in my Ember.js app that will allow me to pass in a view property that is a simple html string to be rendered without being escaped. My template looks like this:

```
  <span class="add-on">{{log view.append}}{{safeMarkup view.append}}</span>
```

In this case the log statement outputs the html string properly to the console, something like `<span>text</span>`.

My helper, safeMarkup, is as follows:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('safeMarkup', (string) ->
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(string)
)
```

Yet, what gets rendered is not the value of the `view.append` property but the string "view.append" itself! Like so: `<span class="add-on">view.append</span>`. Any ideas what's going wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: you can do the same thing as for the `unbound` helper (see http://goo.gl/OenIM), but I do not know why is it a string instead of the property directly.

Comment: What sort of thing is `view.append`? What does `console.log(string)` say inside your helper?

Comment: its the string `view.append`, just take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/E8UzU/

Comment: But your fiddle works fine. I see an `a` in the output and it is even handling embedded HTML properly: http://jsfiddle.net/CwFUu/

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sohara/Dk3Q8/1/) based @muistooshort 's above that demonstrate's what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

In handlebar:

```
{{span 'className'}}
```

In app:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('span', function(className) {
  return new Handlebars.SafeString("<span class='"+Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(className)+"'></span>");
});
```

Comment: add some explanation and this will help this answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also use triple-mustache to avoid escaping of the html string...
     http://jsbin.com/imafuq/8/edit